# Parsing CRL using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificate, pyopenssl

Using below code snippet I am able to get CRL object from a CRL certificate:

```
import OpenSSL

with open('/Users/goutamdas/Desktop/Certificate/My_Certs/crl_ocsp.pem', 'r') as _crl_file:
    crl = "".join(_crl_file.readlines())
print(crl)

crl_object = OpenSSL.crypto.load_crl(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, crl)
print("obj: ", crl_object)
```

Now I want to parse the below 2 dates from this CRL file, and looks like OpenSSL don't provide any relative method to extract. Any suggestion how I can do this.

```
    Last Update: Sep 17 18:01:34 2018 GMT
    Next Update: Oct 17 18:01:34 2018 GMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes exposed via `pyopenssl` are limited, you are often better off switching to the more powerful classes from the [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module, which is used under the hood. For example, for CRLs, you can get access to the class [`cryptography.x509.CertificateRevocationList`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-crl-certificate-revocation-list-object), via the `to_cryptography()` method documented [here](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#crl-objects). It exposes the attributes you are looking for. Continuing with what you did:

```
ccrl_object = crl_object.to_cryptography()
print(ccrl_object.last_update)
print(ccrl_object.next_update)
```

yields something along the lines of

```
2005-02-06 12:00:00
2005-02-05 12:00:00
```